# Error while uploading a file with gzipped content via HTTP POST

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to upload a file using HTTP POST sampler, at the same time compressing the file content. For this, I have added Content-Encoding:gzip in the Header Manager and in the pre processor of the sampler added following code

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;


String bodyString = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
byte [] requestBody = bodyString.getBytes();

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(requestBody.length);
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
gzip.write(requestBody);
gzip.close();

sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(out.toString(0));
```

This was not working and it was throwing following exception

```
2019-08-07 14:08:21,970 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;   S . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : at Line: 5 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;   S . . . '' : .getValue ( ) 

Target exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke method getValue on null value
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;   S . . . '' at line number 5
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:87) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:225) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:935) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:537) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
```

Now to debug added log.info("sampler-------:"+sampler) before getValue like

```
log.info("sampler-------:"+sampler);
String bodyString = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
```

But in the logs sampler returned empty

```
Query Data:
```

So how should I access the file content in the HTTP Request and at the same time gzip it and send?

Answer (score 0):

To gzip the file and its contents use the following code and put it in JSR223 Sampler [this should be before calling POST API] and the assumption is payload data is already copied to a file.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

String source_filepath = "C:/Sample/Input.txt";
String destinaton_zip_filepath = "C:/Sample/Input.gzip";

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =new FileOutputStream(destinaton_zip_filepath);

            GZIPOutputStream gzipOuputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(source_filepath);

            int bytes_read;

            while ((bytes_read = fileInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                gzipOuputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
            }

            fileInput.close();

            gzipOuputStream.finish();
            gzipOuputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

vars.put("ZipFileLocation",destinaton_zip_filepath);
```

Now the gzip file can be used via `${ZipFileLocation}` variable.

It is up to how the API is called, following can be the solution:

- Directly send this gzip file in the API
- Declare a variable and hold all your payload data into it and then call the API -> gzip it

Note : Correct MIME type and Headers need to be used wherever applicable

Comment: this will compress the file content but the Request Body also contains additional info like    ------WebKitFormBoundaryAAMJkD48up3oIqVt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Input.gzip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream     <Compressed content> ------WebKitFormBoundaryAAMJkD48up3oIqVt     Because of which the server is throwing not GZIPPED format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a [file upload with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter/), to wit your file is being passed via "Files Upload" section - you will not be able to get anything using [getArguments()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getArguments--) function, you will need to use [getHTTPFiles()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getHTTPFiles--) instead, suggested algorithm:

1. Get the required file path like:

   ```
   def plainFile = sampler.getHTTPFiles()[0].path
   ```
2. Compress the file according to your server expectations
3. Replace the original file path with compressed file path

   ```
   sampler.getHTTPFiles()[0].setPath("/path/to/compressed/file.gz")
   ```